# Prove the number of conjugates of K in L is $[Gal(L|F) : N]$ where $N$ is the normalizer subgroup

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, field-theory, galois-theory, normal-subgroups

Let $F ⊂ L$ be Galois and $F ⊂ K ⊂ L$ be an intermediate field. Given
$σ_1K, · · · , σ_rK$ are the distinct conjugates of $K$ where
$σ_1 = e$ and $σ_j ∈ Gal(L|F), 1 ≤ j ≤ r$, I wish to prove $r = [Gal(L|F) : N]$ where $N$ is the normaliser subgroup $N_{Gal(L|F )}(Gal(L|K))$.

First, I want to show $Gal(L|F)$ acts on the set of conjugates {$ σ_1K, · · · , σ_rK $}. Second, if we can show the isotropy subgroup of $K$ or $Stab_{Gal(L|F )}(K)$ is the normalizer subgroup $N$, then I think the desired result can be deduced from the Fundamental Theorem of Group Actions, if I am not mistaken. But I am not sure of the details hmm~

Answer (score 1):

Let $G=Gal(L/F)$ and $H=Gal(L/K)$ be the subgroup corresponding to the intermediate field $K$. Let $\sigma\in G$ be arbitrary. By basic properties of group actions (also easy to verify as an exercise, ask if you need help in this step) $\sigma(K)$ is the field of fixed points of the conjugate subgroup
$\sigma H\sigma^{-1}$.

The Galois correspondence is bijective, so for any two automorphisms $\sigma,\sigma'\in G$ we have $\sigma(K)=\sigma'(K)$ if and only if $\sigma H\sigma^{-1}=\sigma' H\sigma'^{-1}$ if and only if $\sigma'\sigma^{-1}$ belongs to the normalizer $N_G(H)$. This means that the conjugate fields $\sigma(K)$ are in a bijective correspondence with the (left) cosets $\sigma N_G(H)$ of the normalizer.

Therefore the number of conjugate intermdiate fields $\sigma(K)$ is equal to
$r=[G:N_G(H)]$ as claimed.

Comment: The fact $\sigma(K)=\operatorname{Inv}(\sigma H\sigma^{-1})$ also implies that the stabilizer of $K$ in $G$ is equal to $N_G(H)$. All according to your outlined plan.

Comment: Ah I see thanks, still in the process of understanding. Then is the first part where $Gal(L|F)$ acts on the set of conjugates {$ σ_1K, · · · , σ_rK $} shown anywhere in your answer?

Comment: Not really @Homaniac :-) That does follow from the fact that $\sigma(\sigma_i K)=(\sigma\sigma_i)K$. Because $\sigma_1,\ldots,\sigma_r$ form a set of representatives of left cosets of $N_G(H)$ we have $\sigma\sigma_i=\sigma_j\eta$ for some $j=1,\ldots,r$ and some $\eta\in N_G(H)$. Then $\eta(K)=K$ and therefore $(\sigma\sigma_i)K=\sigma_j K$.

Comment: Does $\sigma(K)$ is the field of fixed points of the conjugate subgroup
$\sigma H\sigma^{-1}$ follow similarly or from another set of properties of group actions haha cus I don't get that part ><

Comment: If $\alpha=\sigma\beta\sigma^{-1}$ where $\beta\in H$, then, for all $x\in K$, we have
$$\alpha(\sigma(x))=\sigma(\beta(x))=\sigma(x).$$
Therefore $\sigma(K)\subseteq\operatorname{Inv}(\sigma H\sigma^{-1})$. The other direction can be done either in the same way or by using the general consequence of Galois correspondence that the fixed fields of $H$ and $\sigma H\sigma^{-1}$ have the same extension degree over $F$. Hence, if one is contained in the other they must be equal.